# Spring data for mongodb-3.6.0

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-data, spring-data-mongodb

Is there any compatible version of `spring-data-mongo` available for `mongo 3.6.0`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With 2.1

The related issue is [here](https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATAMONGO-1846) and [here](https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATAMONGO-1824)

[Full issue list](https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATAMONGO/fixforversion/16374/?selectedTab=com.atlassian.jira.plugins.jira-development-integration-plugin:release-report-tabpanel)

It is not yet released

Github repo: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-mongodb with instructions how to use the current snapshot

Comment: "Full issue list" link is 403